# Parse Response Entity with CXF Rest client

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf

I'm working with CXF 2.3.2, I made this REST Service:

Interface:

```
@WebMethod
@GET
@Path("/object/{id}")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML})
public Response object(@PathParam("id") Long id);
```

Impl:

```
@Override
public Response object(Long id) {

    CompanyVO company = new CompanyVO();
    company.setAddress("address");
    company.setFantasyName("fantasy name");
    company.setFiscalId("fiscalid");
    company.setGroups("groups");

    return Response.ok().type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).entity(company).build();
}
```

I need to consume that service using a CXF REST Client and obtain the object Entity inside de Response as a Java Object, not as a InputStream.

I made a first implementation as follows, using a ResponseReader class to wrap my Java Class:

```
String operation = "/object/{id}";

    ResponseReader reader = new ResponseReader();
    reader.setEntityClass(CompanyVO.class); 

    WebClient client = WebClient.create(PATH,  Collections.singletonList(reader));
    client.path(operation, 12L);
    client.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    client.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

    //the response's entity object should be this Class.
    CompanyVO company = new CompanyVO();

    Response response = client.get();

    //i get the entity object as a InputStream, but i need a CompanyVO.
    //i made this once, but i can't see the difference.
    Object entity = response.getEntity();
```

Maybe i made the service wrong or the client has  a bad conf. i need your help, please!

The service is was configurated using Spring 3.0.5:

```
<jaxrs:server id="serviceAdvisorRestServer" address="/rest">

    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="fileService"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

     <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
        <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"/>
        <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
        <entry key="pdf" value="application/pdf"></entry>
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
```

Thanks!

Comment: check this link (http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/How-to-convert-response-input-stream-to-java-object-td3350746.html) may be it will help you

Comment: @ Konstantin V. Salikhov, My implementation described above seems to be the same as the examples...but it doesn't work, i'dont want an inputstream, i want my object as the Response.getEntity. thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of getting the Response object by invoking the get method on client try this:

```
CompanyVO company = client.get(CompanyVO.class);
```

I think this might be able to solve your problem.

Have a look at webclient [api](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/cxf/cxf-bundle-jaxrs/2.3.2/cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.3.2-javadoc.jar!/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/WebClient.html)

Also i dont think you would need @Consumes annotation on your webservice method for application/json etc... as you are using a Path parameter in the method.

Answer (score 1):

No clean solution here for CXF 2.3.X except switching to the usage of proxies with JAXRSClientFactory or use the double calls (get() - get(someclass.class). The webclient does' t support the reader provider.

CXF 2.7.X implements JAX-RS 2.0 (almost) and from this version on you can call client.readEntity().

Answer (score 0):

For the **Proxy API** it should work like this:

Try:

```
ResponseReader reader = new ResponseReader();
reader.setEntityClass(CompanyVO.class); 

InterfaceClass proxy = JAXRSClientFactory.create(PATH, InterfaceClass.class, Collections.singletonList(reader));
```

Then:

```
Response res = proxy.get();
CompanyVO company = (CompanyVO) res.getEntity();
```

For the **WebClient** it should work quite the same:

Try:

```
ResponseReader reader = new ResponseReader();
reader.setEntityClass(CompanyVO.class); 

WebClient client = WebClient.create(PATH, Collections.singletonList(reader));
```

Then:

```
Response res = client.get();
CompanyVO company = (CompanyVO) res.getEntity();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this doesn't work for me. I am still getting a ClassCastException when it tries to cast the InputStream of getEntity() to CompanyVO. (CXF 2.5.2) How does it know that the returned data is really a CompanyVO object? The documentation shows this being performed on a proxy - does it work with WebClient also?

Comment: nice one user1189762. This is the only concise example I can remember seeing on how to implement a ResponseReader. Short sweet and to the point. Good job.

Comment: To bad it is not correct for the webclient. It is not possible to hook a reader to the web client. There is a solution with JAX-RS 2.0 spec which is implemented in CXF 2.7.X . See Response#readEntity(). Otherwise you are stuck to switching to the proxy mechanisme or the double invokes.